# Maya Python/Mel : Retrieve name of last object deleted

Tags: python, scripting, maya, mel

Was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the name of the last object deleted.

I have looked into listHistory, but that seems to list the history of a selected or named object. I have also looked into undoHistory printqueue, which prints out the undo history into the script editor, but i can't retrieve that information from the console.

Any ideas? I've looked around and can't find any info on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible after the fact. Have you looked into a `scriptJob` that watches for deletions?

Comment: As a workaround I'm using a scriptJob to store last selection which is working - just feels like there should be a way of retrieving this info.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list with:

```
undoInfo -q -pq;
```

There are a few really really good use cases for scalping Maya undo. Such as determining selection order after the fact. In any case it may be difficult to know what it actually was form the queue so you may need to undo and redo to get what the deleted object was.

So this may or may not work, mileage may vary.

As a side note since your restoring stuff why not save the object list at time of save. The order is going to be the same (ensured), so you can see the changes in the end and deletions as missing objects. See the objects in in a plain ls are in creation order. You can use this for rudimentary diff from import to import for example. Same works for deletions.

Answer (score 0):

Catching any individual deletion after the fact is not possible. However you can stick an `attributeDeleted` scriptJob on objects you want to monitor - it will fire when they are deleted.  If you really want to catch every object, a scriptJob listening for the event `DagObjectCreated` will let you hook the other scriptJob to each new object - however that's not a good idea most of the time, since it will create a ton of scriptJobs in your scene (plus you'd have to also loop through the scene on load and attach the same deletion callback to existing objects as well...)

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

def objectDeleted(obj):
    print "%s was deleted" % obj

def catch_deletion(obj):
   cmds.scriptJob ( attributeDeleted = ( (obj + ".tx"), partial(objectDeleted, obj) ) )

catch_deletion('pCube1')
```

Comment: dont be so strict, it may be possible to catch deletion after the fact, with undoInfo.

Comment: I really don't think this is possible for the general case; the undo queue stores MPxCommands which only expose doIt()'s and undoIt()'s, not whatever internal arrangements they make to keep things undoable or redoable. OP would be responsible for auditing the scene regardless.

Comment: No but you get a hint and can unroll the undo queue to investigate further. But see this is what the op asked. Anyway i did use May to indicate it is not necessarily possible.

Comment: Fair enough - I just don't think it's worth OP's time: there's lots of ways it can go wrong outside the 'select x; DoDelete();` case